# Moving a folder between git repositories does not preserve the folder itself

Tags: git

I followed a [great tutorial](http://st-on-it.blogspot.co.il/2010/01/how-to-move-folders-between-git.html) on how to move a folder between git repos while preserving history. I encountered the following issue though:

Suppose I have the following structure in my source repo:

```
Root/
  SubRoot/
   A
   B
   C
```

I want to move A and B to another repo.

First problem: `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter` can work only with one directory :-(. I am willing to repeat the process more than once, but is there a better way?

Second problem (the really bad one): when I moved A, it moved its contents but did not preserve the directory A itself, giving me:

```
Root/
    <contents of A>
```

Instead of:

```
Root/
    A/
     <contents of A>
```

The command I executed (from Root):

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter SubRoot/A -- --a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no better approach. This is the way to go.

I had to do the filter-subtree for each directory I wanted to move, each time starting from a fresh clone.

After each filter I used git mv to align the desired directory structure.

Important note: for some reason tortoisegit was unable to track the history. I switched to Sourcetree that is much better and faster- had no trouble to see the history there.